# How to add a title to a concat in Vega-Lite

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, vega, deneb

How do I add a title to each concat in a spec?

- I'd like to insert titles on top of every concat.

[Here's what I did so far (preview/code here)](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoALI0oAJzYACKIKQQINAGbmkAL3ay41-tYAicLJsCAD6aCAAyjBs9gCeiiAAcgwItvaOAXCYFmqYbBY0aABMAAwAnEopaXYOENYACnU0xEWoAIztYlWp6XWNVghs+YVoAMwA7KVKAIKkuWQ+bM4BAKKRoZGrSQAqAJIm2zto-KWU7QC+CqbmVn2OLm6ecj5+gcFhEQDCIXDKcdZltYdnALFYLBAFMD4Ilqvd6oEcnkCm12sUACw9GoZepNB6tNBTCZY+EDELDFFodFjMazeZIRaAlb+dabI4HI7jSgANiuN0sNlqD1cUA8XleWQ+4XQOxsACElhZrElhtZ8tYFbDekKEdlcthKagxMV2iSdY1mgTUOjubTktqcWShiM2uipnTQQylszWVtdhzdmh2jy+SAzAL4Y9Rc9vL5JSFpSAvkgcJgWnQEmbHYj9S6gzas-08U4rTTioXMg1BhTRqgxhUPQtvWsNn79odA3XKBNQ+G7jqo2KXnH3gmIgB5BhKgBqNG89QAEkhSMCgspQdYAOK5HD6LXY-o55G1srde0HyuWtrcibl8+kqvkvOobliO1zT2MoEs1vsjvHVB+DGbte1uQUcUHGMJVHT50AAJSQLALDgOBUGsAAxQQ2AAdw3IF6B8JIaDILBrAACjlBgcBwGAkGsBCkJQgBKfdSSPA1a3RUozzhc1i3TIN2mJe8+OrZ8um5RsvSZFs2X9f8SkoAAOUCIwHEUh1jN4gjHdAAGk5H4HYaAAayKCtdSRDi2nKMoLItfEbNKO1eMdR9nUNE1TRAD8mxkn85PbTlAPRSgxFU-sII0qCRx02CQB2JATKCVjzXY58JgmSoRLcq9CTGJT7PcmtrwmTEfPpL8fV-eTguAy5rjDMDI2i8VYqlCI5UKWQyEBWQ1XgZViKwVLsz1Y82gmV8iry61uW81yizEw10XKaYKs-ZsArbAMANC3lGr7cDmla4dtI69ATAZWQoyCTBrHHJgIH0Jw5FGw9xustAlPmmbHLQW1ssWytltrJSxGy3zpO-X0-zqiLjuFJ42vO3SojM-rNyQBA4HezJ0sNMR0QWh0i1m8olMKnKlqfQ0hMkja-Jhmqgs7IDKHKBGWuRs743iuUaEEQRrAAMlXZQAHJ6lWAAPKA4CFu7rBmZRSFkTAp1x+yCZPJT1uB3FZrGcogdJkHadrcoxjPKGqtknaFMAs5OcO5r1J5rS+cTaIkAsEy4il6wrtgOctep-HPufJSsr+ks2mKcGitB1FuUhyqtth2rO2AlTXbUqKPeguLvd+AIkDieoZmQjVskwDcdlo-rxwIiE8cs3MVtKO8DYcuOAfRcqe+K8SY8Z6HqsC3aTmKSh0S593oxRr2In8Oc2AgJApwYCAAEI26yKznzdBmh9mqYSYvXFk7QY0bfT-zM9ZgDgx7PPIpOwv2rRq6wRoP41RsARIObAmD7x1m0cGLkzaG3+qgcoYgL4Pmvh0MQd9NoPxZlPQCwExjzwLovXmMFExyiQMoZAshA4-AYOrCwmZw7twmiUCGscBKoCUvApOFtrzcnWrbDOmDHYNX5O-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-7ZoiEdbmJiv6fHlQUT1oAs05oSgCzVQqLA6rafqtcxrHnlLoDItAvahZlM5VhXVWgdB6FFX8VZFxQzRolUOwtxb0B1xlkq+Vhb93oHsEwBWO7E1sGTSaodg750jsXeOhemlTFjhnYqjNC71WYrqIkbVka9XQC3Sm29Sh01DsQ7m+5DjzLlKLW8stFa0zqDTKQRIVGv0gD2JUwDRqql5GhQWuAb6EPgYiBS-NpHn0gAo5W6jNbEjVOiWoCIlBSgAFIb2yp5TQP1MAA3rWDSRUNLKlARt1d6+9sb41KAA0BjNeGwOqr4-i6+BayOlvLaJ6ttGC17reZEFj3bnDsfmV2ntfaB08as5dN2+DoNTvCFcvzGaf0K1xd5wQz0ykKrncO4LS6NU4lQ2u9DKhN2Gu3WU+jWzD39tdbEAoGbtC6DeWQZCKVb13t9g+0AT63mvvfSACAn63mxcEP+91gHt0gaC6OkL+djHhdRtOrrs7RuLoxYCxw2X10YYNWZorbmD0Bdw-N6zEKCWjDs0JkTVHnPcs49x-DvHCOHZI21hzlGq00bDpJ5AnqQCyYU41s1oBfX+tQMUQNGA4AhvGDpkAemo3NaM3Ykzg2zNDos2lsbYL8V5WO+RxzZ2Xt0a2+gJIcAGBImEL57t22j1KFAyjiDoXJsxWm5FkF0Wh19fizoJLcHUsEYy8h5bWqcu6ry5hgr2HXOYC-aV49FWz0gGq5e9AcQFZYWwopxqhnH32ZfVxzr3W4gMb6wNpNw3QDU555BsLDPl5c72zKZdWWBereF+twr4vJc7ZAMjnnFKoV0a18J7Hz3xNRfJ6gUrbuSse467btHB2MeCax09sTLnM01Ok+gL7infsgA161-30eymmZNyAM3N2moTdEVN63s34PXfS4tldaGhfrhFxtiPFPBAh-85Tz3MeOVcr9ydwPyew7FY7138fXWGkNpUCEJAc4jCmnaKUorOu++cuQoPxPTncdKDe+nz7pRnA3qUP9tTdYNOg60+D0oTWY2a6EwX+HxuU0jbr6ji39Ol4SJt+-hb9uUNHdcsW8Xcxdd0JdI8hYJ8w8Pcvcy88kJ4ClAxMdHsd9g9wD3coDmdQ9w8p960M1+VkAF8vUl8V9Ltud4DfFEC4ZkCE9UCcd0D98PtZNj8cMfUVMAd6wg0r8RoL9b91cYcH92s19C8Edi9S90tP9K8rcf8a8KD68AD+dV0ncQCsMTVNsIDJ9O0cDYCY8G8Hc6D0BTsg8U8x8YCsDtDu9O88Cv1QBCD595ASCFBl82Do8-8kMls5FDCA8k9zsJM09mCj8T92DVNwduCwc+ClMgA)

[image]

Here's an example of the result I'd like to achieve:
[image]

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Can  you break this into the individual constituent questions as they each have different and sometimes complex treatment strategies.

Comment: I'll answer one of the questions here and update your text. Please add individual questions for your other queries and try and have a smaller minimal reproducible sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get titles, just add a title to each concat spec.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Sholay",
        "Num class Detrattori": 209,
        "Num class Passivi": 115,
        "Num class Promotori": 370,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": -0.1
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Comedy of Terrors, The",
        "Num class Detrattori": 124,
        "Num class Passivi": 707,
        "Num class Promotori": 433,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": 3.6
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "To Be or Not to Be",
        "Num class Detrattori": 521,
        "Num class Passivi": 463,
        "Num class Promotori": 470,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": 1.6
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Captivity",
        "Num class Detrattori": 146,
        "Num class Passivi": 332,
        "Num class Promotori": 309,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": 3.7
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Our Vines Have Tender Grapes",
        "Num class Detrattori": 205,
        "Num class Passivi": 672,
        "Num class Promotori": 653,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": -3.7
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Rahtree: Flower of the Night (Buppha Rahtree)",
        "Num class Detrattori": 405,
        "Num class Passivi": 117,
        "Num class Promotori": 156,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": 2.8
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Kon-Tiki",
        "Num class Detrattori": 920,
        "Num class Passivi": 903,
        "Num class Promotori": 211,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": -4.5
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Taken",
        "Num class Detrattori": 779,
        "Num class Passivi": 738,
        "Num class Promotori": 674,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": 3.1
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Bring on the Night",
        "Num class Detrattori": 765,
        "Num class Passivi": 461,
        "Num class Promotori": 490,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": 4.6
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Magnificent Obsession",
        "Num class Detrattori": 861,
        "Num class Passivi": 639,
        "Num class Promotori": 859,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": 3
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Skin Game",
        "Num class Detrattori": 541,
        "Num class Passivi": 988,
        "Num class Promotori": 176,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": -3.9
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Bill & Ted's Excellent Adventure",
        "Num class Detrattori": 280,
        "Num class Passivi": 399,
        "Num class Promotori": 935,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": -0.9
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Sharky's Machine",
        "Num class Detrattori": 879,
        "Num class Passivi": 285,
        "Num class Promotori": 169,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": 3.8
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Some Days Are Better Than Others",
        "Num class Detrattori": 402,
        "Num class Passivi": 644,
        "Num class Promotori": 179,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": -2.4
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Dinosaurus!",
        "Num class Detrattori": 476,
        "Num class Passivi": 701,
        "Num class Promotori": 525,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": 1.7
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Married to the Mob",
        "Num class Detrattori": 853,
        "Num class Passivi": 951,
        "Num class Promotori": 155,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": -3.3
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Badman's Country",
        "Num class Detrattori": 259,
        "Num class Passivi": 895,
        "Num class Promotori": 660,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": 1
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Chillers",
        "Num class Detrattori": 417,
        "Num class Passivi": 905,
        "Num class Promotori": 662,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": 1.5
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Alien Hunter",
        "Num class Detrattori": 359,
        "Num class Passivi": 377,
        "Num class Promotori": 400,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": -3.8
      },
      {
        "Micro classificazione - Denom_": "Tormento",
        "Num class Detrattori": 867,
        "Num class Passivi": 484,
        "Num class Promotori": 984,
        "Average of DES_SENTIMENT": -4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "datum['Num class Detrattori']+datum['Num class Passivi']+datum['Num class Promotori']",
      "as": "Totalclass"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum['Num class Detrattori']/datum['Totalclass']",
      "as": "PercDetrattori"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum['Num class Passivi']/datum['Totalclass']",
      "as": "PercPassivi"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum['Num class Promotori']/datum['Totalclass']",
      "as": "PercPromotori"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "(datum['PercPromotori']-datum['PercDetrattori'])*100",
      "as": "Score"
    },
    {
      "window": [{"op": "rank", "as": "rank"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "Totalclass", "order": "descending"}]
    },
    {"filter": "datum.rank < 11"}
  ],
  "concat": [
    {
      "width": 260,
      "height": 300,
      "title":"My Title",
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": "bar",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "PercDetrattori",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"reverse": true},
              "axis": null
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "Micro classificazione - Denom_",
              "sort": {"field": "Totalclass", "order": "descending"},
              "title": null
            },
            "color": {"value": "red"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "text", "style": "label"},
          "encoding": {
            "y": {
              "field": "Micro classificazione - Denom_",
              "sort": {"field": "Totalclass", "order": "descending"}
            },
            "x": {
              "field": "PercDetrattori",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": "Insoddisfatti"
            },
            "text": {
              "field": "PercDetrattori",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "format": ".0%"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "width": 260,
      "height": 300,
      "title":"My Title",
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": "bar",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "PercPromotori",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": "Soddisfatti",
              "axis": null
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "Micro classificazione - Denom_",
              "axis": {"labels": false},
              "sort": {"field": "Totalclass", "order": "descending"},
              "title": null
            },
            "color": {"value": "green"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "text", "style": "label"},
          "encoding": {
            "y": {
              "field": "Micro classificazione - Denom_",
              "sort": {"field": "Totalclass", "order": "descending"},
              "title": null
            },
            "x": {"field": "PercPromotori", "type": "quantitative"},
            "text": {
              "field": "PercPromotori",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "format": ".0%"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "width": 260,
      "height": 300,
      "title":"My Title",
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": "bar",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "PercPassivi",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": "Neutrali",
              "axis": null
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "Micro classificazione - Denom_",
              "axis": {"labels": false},
              "sort": {"field": "Totalclass", "order": "descending"},
              "title": null
            },
            "color": {"value": "yellow"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "text", "style": "label"},
          "encoding": {
            "y": {
              "field": "Micro classificazione - Denom_",
              "sort": {"field": "Totalclass", "order": "descending"},
              "title": null
            },
            "x": {
              "field": "PercPassivi",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null,
              "title": null
            },
            "text": {
              "field": "PercPassivi",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "format": ".0%"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title":"My Title",
      "mark": {"type": "text"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "Micro classificazione - Denom_",
          "sort": {"field": "Totalclass", "order": "descending"},
          "title": null,
          "axis": null
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "Score",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": null,
          "axis": null,
          "scale": {"domain": [1, 1]}
        },
        "text": {"field": "Score", "type": "quantitative", "format": ".0f"}
      },
      "width": 30,
      "height": 300
    },
    {
      "title":"My Title",
      "mark": {"type": "text"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "Micro classificazione - Denom_",
          "sort": {"field": "Totalclass", "order": "descending"},
          "title": null,
          "axis": null
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "Average of DES_SENTIMENT",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": null,
          "axis": null,
          "scale": {"domain": [1, 1]}
        },
        "text": {
          "field": "Average of DES_SENTIMENT",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "format": ".0f"
        }
      },
      "width": 30,
      "height": 300
    },
    {
      "title":"My Title",
      "mark": {"type": "text"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "Micro classificazione - Denom_",
          "sort": {"field": "Totalclass", "order": "descending"},
          "title": null,
          "axis": null
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "Totalclass",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": null,
          "axis": null,
          "scale": {"domain": [1, 1]}
        },
        "text": {"field": "Totalclass", "type": "quantitative", "format": ".0f"}
      },
      "width": 30,
      "height": 300
    }
  ]
}
```